# How do I escape a table whose name is a reserved SQL keyword?

Tags: c#, sql

I've been working with databases in my WPF Application and when I try to execute my command it keeps giving me an SqlException. It's some kind of typing error and it's probably very silly but i've been stuck on this for a while and just cannot figure it out.

```
string selectStatement = "SELECT * FROM Order ORDER BY OrderDate DESC;";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, connection);
        SqlDataReader reader = null;

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

This is a picture of the table:
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiZ1Z.jpg)

Comment: You'll need to also tell us what the exception says.

Comment: `ORDER` is a SQL keyword and should never be used as a table name or table alias.

Comment: Delimit it as `"Order"`.

Comment: @Izzy there's nothing wrong with `;` in TSQL

Comment: How do we know it's tsql/sql server? I can only see the sql tag, which means ANSI SQL.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks, I didn't know that

Comment: @jarlh the `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` tells us that

Comment: I thought that was some c# stuff...

Comment: paste exception maybe?

Comment: (note: please don't edit the title to include "(fixed)" to indicate that it is fixed; the way to do that is to accept an answer)

Answer (score 4):

```
const string selectStatement = "SELECT * FROM [Order] ORDER BY OrderDate DESC;";
```

should fix it

Comment: Thanks! It fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server: use it between [] (`SELECT * FROM [Order];`)

Oracle: use it between "" (`SELECT * FROM "Order"`) <- Just watch out that it becomes case sensitive.